# how do i retrieve data from firebase without listening for changes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to create an application that uses firebase as a backend.Now the problem I have is that I have to attach a listener to get back a snapshot of data. But for every time my application starts,I want to query firebase for data and populate my views even though there has been no change in the database.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: the answer should be here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#child-events

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you are doing something like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Code 
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Code
        }
    });
```

So for what I think you're asking, calling an alternative method called `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` should solve the problem. It will **not** listen for changes, as soon as returns a value, it will stop connecting until being attached again.

---

**Result**

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Code 
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Code
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you....I now get it....the problem was that the name of the overriding method onDatachange was misleading,i thought it was invoked only when data is changed

Comment: Been long i worked on firebase, had this issue for about a week, thinking backend could be the problem.You saved my Friday!